# kendo ui datasource cancel read from within read function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have the read function, i want to make sure that value for parameter is present, if not
cancel the read event. How can i cancel the ajax Call from within Read ?

```
read: {
            url: function (e) {
                try {
                    //var OrgHeadQrtrID_PK = 0;

                    if (e.orgHeadQuarterIdPK == null)
                        **--not sure how to cancel this read**

                    return baseURL + "/GetOrgs";

                } catch (e) {
                    console.error("Error occured in the read method of module " + moduleName);
                    console.trace();
                }


            }, // "/PutOrgSchool",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  requestStart: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

use  e.preventDefault(); to prevent a read request, however create/update/destroy requests cannot be prevented. You can set these options as functions and prevent them manually. How to set them to a function is explained here:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can cancel it from the read function, but you can from [requestStart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#events-requestStart) however, I'm not sure you can get the parameters from there.